# How to get image height and width from uri on React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So, I tried to use function that provided by React Native which is Image.getSize. But when I try to use height and width outside the function it appears to be nil.
Here is my code:

```
var theHeight = 0;
Image.getSize(url,(height, width)=>{
 theHeight = height;
})

console.log("test get height "+theHeight);
```

and the result would be

> test get height 0

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The first is that `Image.getSize` invokes its callbacks asynchronously. You need to put your code that relies on the image size within the callbacks.

The second problem is that the arguments to the success callback are `(width, height)`, not the other way around.

You should write:

```
Image.getSize(url, (width, height) => {
  console.log(`The image dimensions are ${width}x${height}`);
}, (error) => {
  console.error(`Couldn't get the image size: ${error.message}`);
});
```

Comment: I know that, but how can I use width and height outside success callback?

Comment: You can assign the width and height to variables outside of the callback as long as you access those variables only after the callback has completed.

Comment: I tried your code and I realize that "console.log("test get height "+theHeight);" called before the callback has completed. How can I update var after the callback has completed?

Comment: You could set the variable in the callback the way you'd do it in any other code or programming language, there's nothing special about React Native here.

Comment: I put my code inside the callback and it works but with a very short delay

Comment: Yes, there's a delay, that's why there's a callback. You have to structure your code and design your app to accommodate the delay.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how I do this within a Redux Saga (where I need it to block until it is competed):

```
const getImageSize = new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    Image.getSize(filePath, (width, height) => {
      resolve({ width, height });
    });
  },
  (error) => reject(error)
);

const { width, height } = yield getImageSize;

console.log(`width ${width}, height ${height}`);
```

You could also call the promise with an await (inside an async function), just in case someone else needs this.